# Twilio inbound request url failed due to https

Tags: laravel, twilio

I am using twilio service for sms functionality in my laravel application.I am also using sms stop functionality using inbound request URL.Also enabled auto-messanger service.All is working fine with http url but not working with https.I know twilio uses strict SSL validation to work it properly.For this,I email twilio support and they replied that your SSL rating is "F".To work it properly twilio needs "A" rating.After this discussion,now my SSL rating is A but still not woking.After this twilio replied:-

"The Twilio server is expecting a Twiml in return if its 200 ok. You can return a HTTP 204 No Content, with no response body, if you like. Or if it's easier you can set the response to "Content-Type: text/plain" and return a 0-length response body."

I have set header type "text/plain" and content-length = 0  but i think this is not working.

When inbound request call then inbound request url call automatically and function below execute:-

```
public function stopSms() {

    $response = Response::make('', 200, ['Content-Length' => 0]);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

    $sms_response = Input::all();
    $body_name = trim($sms_response['Body'], '"');
    $phone_number = trim($sms_response['From'], '"');
    $user = User::where('phone_number', '=', $phone_number);
    if ($user->count()) {
        if ($body_name == "OPT-OUT" || $body_name == "STOP" || $body_name == "END" || $body_name == "QUIT" || $body_name == "CANCEL" || $body_name == "UNSUBSCRIBE") {
            // To get user info
            $user = $user->first();
            $user->sms_consent = 0;
            if ($user->save()) {
                Sms::send(array('to' => "$phone_number", 'text' => "You will no longer receive sms messages from Simplistic Sentiments. To start messages, reply OPT-IN or reply with HELP for more options"));
                return $response;
            }
        } else if ($body_name == "OPT-IN" || $body_name == "START" || $body_name == "YES") {
            // To get user info
            $user = $user->first();
            $user->sms_consent = 1;
            if ($user->save()) {
                Sms::send(array('to' => "$phone_number", 'text' => "You will now receive sms messages from Simplistic Sentiments. To stop messages, reply OPT-OUT or reply with HELP for more options"));
                return $response;
            }
        } else if ($body_name == "HELP" || $body_name == "INFO") {
            // To get user info
            $txt = "To stop messages reply with these keyword: \n";
            $txt .= "OPT-OUT,STOP,END,QUIT and UNSUBSCRIBE\n";
            $txt .= "To start messages reply with these keyword: \n";
            $txt .= "OPT-IN,START and YES";
            try {
                Sms::send(array('to' => "$phone_number", 'text' => $txt));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
            return $response;
        } else {
            Sms::send(array('to' => "$phone_number", 'text' => "You entered wrong keyword. Please enter correct keyword. To stop, reply OPT-OUT and to Start, reply OPT-IN"));
            return $response;
        }
    }else{
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks

Comment: If you make a POST request to your endpoint, what response do you see at the moment?

Comment: Hi Philnash...Thanks for your reply.
Here is my curl example:-
 $ curl --dump-header - -X POST 'https://www.xxxxx.com/sms_response' --data-urlencode 'From=+916754876545'
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2016 03:43:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.6.17
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.17
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Ah, ok, I missed something here. What do you mean it's not working? What happens when your server returns this?

Comment: Actually when inbound request call then twilio failed inbound url request...     Error:     11200 HTTP retrieval failure.It only failed when ssl validation enabled but working fine when we disabled it.

Comment: Ok, so there's still an issue with the ssl then. Can you send me an email at philnash@twilio.com with your URL and I'll try to see what I can find out about it. Thanks!

Comment: yes.. issue is in ssl. I have sent URL with complete function to  your specified email.Thanks for your support.